# .htaccess apache - Page loading logic

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to show a page "/ua/index.html" if it exists, if not load another "/index.html".
Difference in patch.

I tried setting like this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ua/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^$ /ua/index.html [L]
```

for home page examples: example.com - if exists "/ua/index.html" load it or not load "/index.html"

for other pages examples:
example.com/ua/page1.html - if exists "/ua/page1.html" load it or not load "/index.html"

Update 3:

MrWhite said about the error with a slash, in fact I need this code, but it creates a lot of redirects ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
RewriteRule ^ua/index.html$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ua/index.html -f
RewriteRule .* /ua/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(ru|ua)/([^/]+).html$ /?lang=$1&tema=$2 [L]
```

Comment: From your directives, you are requesting the document root only?

Comment: @MrWhite the first page in the directory, the second from the root

Comment: Yes, but what is the URL you are requesting? The URL you type in the browser.

Comment: @MrWhite I need this to work for the main and other pages

Comment: So, _all_ URLs? `/`, `/foo`, `/bar` and `/foo/bar` are all rooted to `/ua/index.html` if it exists, otherwise `/index.html`? But presumably static resources like `/images/myimage.jpg` and `/styles/mydesign.css` should be served as-is?

Comment: no.
I will now describe in more detail in the topic of the question.

Answer (score 1):

From your updated question it looks like you just need a standard front-controller pattern?

For example, try the following (using mod_dir):

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

This will allow any file to be served if it exists, otherwise, it falls back to serving `/index.html` if the requested file does not exist.

For example, if you request `/ua/page1.html` and it exists then it will be served, otherwise, `/index.html` will be served.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ua/index.html -f
> RewriteRule ^$ /ua/index.html [L]
> ```

The first *condition* that checks against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable would never match since this *always* starts with a slash. However, this *condition* is superfluous anyway.

Having removed the first *condition*, this would serve the file `example.com/ua/index.html` (if it exists) if you requested `example.com/` (the root only), which does not appear be what you are trying to do.

Comment: This does not solve my problem with accessing the main page. For home page examples: example.com - if exists "/ua/index.html" load it or not load "/index.html" And FallbackResource similar to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^(ru|ua)/([^/]+).html$ /?$1&$2 [L]` I updeted #3 post.